# Manipulation jumps full blender unit

Tags: modeling, transforms, snapping

I am modeling a architecture environment in blender and everything was working fine but must have accidently hit a hot key that I was not aware of. Now when I go to manipulate an object whether it be just moving it around, extruding or grabbing a vertex(face or edge) it now jumps to a full blender unit before moving and so on and so forth. I was wondering if anyone knew how I could change it back to the smooth fluid motion of before?